# ¿Cómo dar estilo a contenido de ActionLinkButton? asp.net mvc razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

¿Puedo hacer modificaciones de estilo solo al contenido de mi `actionLink`? En este caso a la palabra `Excel`, ya que al dar un estilo modifica a todo mi ActionLink, icono y texto.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Excel  ",
                 "ExportarConsultaAlmacen",
                 new { formato = "Excel" },
                 new { @class = "fa fa-file-excel-o btn btn-default" })
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de qué es lo que obtienes actualmente y qué es lo que deseas obtener?

Comment: Quiero quitar solo el texto al hacerse responsivo.

Comment: ¿En tu diseño responsivo utilizas algo como Boostrap o alguna otra herramienta?

Comment: Sí, lo que yo hago es ocultar el texto en responsive. Pero al tratarse de un ActionLink  no puedo ocultar solo el texto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si utilizas Bootstap tal y como comentas, puedes jugar con las clases visible-xx y hidden-xx y crear el ActionLink en dos divs distintos con cada uno de los estados. Estarás duplicando contenido, pero para casos tan concretos como el que tienes, creo que puede ser una buena solución:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

Podrías hacer algo así:

```
<div>
    <div class="visible-xs-*">
        Contenido que se ve en dispositivos de <768px
    </div>
    <div class="hidden-xs">
        Contenido que se ve en el resto de dispositivos
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tienes razón! He añadido un pequeño ejemplo de lo que comento en mi respuesta

Comment: Tienes razón.. conseguí lo que quería

Comment: Hola @CarmenG, me alegro que te haya valido la solución, en ese caso podrías marcar la respuesta como correcta.